# Zero Knowledge Proofs: to establish a public key cryptography encryption

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, mac

I am very interested to know in the general sense how two parties who know each other are able to continue a conversation IF and ONLY IF they both earn the same salary. For example, we have a person X who earns 75000USD, but they only want to continue speaking to person Y IF and ONLY IF person Y also earns 75000USD. They do not really know how much person Y earns but much rather they get a bit of some sort similar to a signature where b=0 if personXSalary != personYSalary and b=1 if personXSalary == personYSalary. Only if b=1, then does person X know the actual salary of person Y

My question is, how would one instantiate such a public key encryption scheme to ensure this? I was thinking of something along the lines of Zero Proof Knowledge but then MACs also was another thought

Comment: [Socialist Millionaires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socialist_millionaires)

Comment: Actually, if they're trying to negotiate and want to succeed only if their salary is the same, any PAKE (Password Authenticated Key Exchange) protocol (with the salary as the password) works nicely...

Comment: @poncho thanks for your suggestion. the only thing is person X who only knows their salary can only go by the bit b that is sent back by person Y. So if the salary of person X & person Y are the same, then b=1. If person X receives the b bit = 1 then they will continue communications. Otherwise the protocol is ended. How could I go about designing it

Comment: @kelalaka thanks for your suggestion. the only thing is person X who only knows their salary can only go by the bit b that is sent back by person Y. So if the salary of person X & person Y are the same, then b=1. If person X receives the b bit = 1 then they will continue communications. Otherwise the protocol is ended. How could I go about designing it

Comment: @usr7337x987986985 poncho's suggestion does exactly what you want. A PAKE will report success (the code may return b=1 in response) only if the inputs are identical, which also covers the case of if the salary numbers are identical or not.

Comment: @Natanael hmm interesting i take it that this is also public key cryptography as well

Comment: @usr7337x987986985 basically yes - PAKE is asymmetric cryptography which often uses public key algorithms as a component, or other related algorithms (like Diffie-Hellman key exchange) which usually can be modified into working as typical public key cryptography (encryption / signing)

Comment: Let each side have salaries $s_1$ and $s_2$ and $hash(s_1)$ and $hash(s_2)$ be their private keys, and their public keys are $g^{hash(s_1)}$ and  $g^{hash(s_2)}$, respectively. Now, transfer El-Gamal encryption of pre-agreed messages. Decrypt and check. The salary space is the weak part.

Answer (score 1):

By using SPAKE2, we can achieve this as Poncho said in comments.

- Let $s_a$ be the salary of Alice
- Let $s_b$ be the salary of Bob
- Let we have Ed25519 curve with the base point G.

Exchange part;

1. Alice  pics a random scalar $x$ and calculates $X = x\cdot G$ and $T = s_1\cdot M+X$, where $M$ is another point on ECC and sends the value $T$ and $M$ to Bob (pake message).
2. Bob pics a random scalar $y$ and calculates $Y= y\cdot G$ and $S = s_2\cdot N + Y $, where $N$ is another point on ECC and sends the value $S$ and $N$ to Alice.

Key calculation part:

- $Key_{Alice} = x ( S - s_a \cdot N) = x ( s_b N + Y - s_a N ) = x(s_b - s_a)+xyG $
- $Key_{Bob} = y ( S - s_b \cdot M) = x ( s_a M + X - s_b M ) = x(s_a - s_b)+xyG $

if $s_a = s_b$ then we will have a cancelation to $xyG$ on both sides. Now, two sides can assume that they have a key agreement, without knowing the equality. They can encrypt pre-agreed plaintexts and sent each other, after this, they can conclude that their salaries are the same if the decryptions are successful, they conclude otherwise if not successful.

After the conclusion of success, one can convert the result into a bit $b$ by;

```
if p1 == Dec(xyG,c1)
   return 1
else
   return 0
```

Comment: How would I incorporate the bit b?

Comment: if $( p_1 == Dec( xyG, c_1)$ then return 1, isn't enough?